# Shell script to convert to Upper-case

Tags: regex, shell

Say I have a `names.dict` file as such:

```
aaren   aa r ah n
abby    ae b iy
....
```

and I would like to have a script that converts the phonetic pronunciation, or whatever is after the spaces into Upper-Case. Beware, I'm new to shell so what I have below is mostly pseudo-code.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=/path/to/names.dict
str temp;
str toUpper;

while read -r line
do
    echo $line > temp  // store the line into a temp string
    regexp="$temp:[[:space:]]*'"  // checks for white space
    //save whatever is after the first white spaces into 'toUpper'
    echo $toUpper | tr [a-z] [A-Z] //this converts the phonetic pronunciation to upper-case

done < "$filename"  //write the Upper-Case string to the original file, replacing the lower-case.
```

But I'm not sure how to setup the regex match statement.

EDIT: link to the file [names.dict](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/product/1491356679_01827/4320.dict)

Comment: You look for a global shell solution or a bash solution?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Global would be preferred but any solution is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more alternatives:
With sed or perl directly - no loop required:

```
sed -E 's/(.[^[:blank:]]+)([[:blank:]])(.*)/\1\2\U\3/g' file
```

Using refexp class [:blank:] we can catch both spaces or tabs.

With `-i` switch to `sed` you can apply changes inplace - directly on file1.
Above solution can also work with `perl`. Just replace `sed -E -i` with `perl -pe -i` and keep the same substitution command. Perl has the advantage that will work on the same way in all platforms.

With bash:

```
while read -r f1 f2;do echo "$f1 ${f2^^}";done<file >newfile
```

In this case, `read` command will assign the first field to variable `$f1` of input line, and all the rest fields to variable `$f2`. Using the default IFS (space, tab,newline) ensures correct handling of white space between f1 and f2.

Testing:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.[^[:blank:]]*)([[:blank:]])(.*)/\1\2\U\3/g' <<<$'one\t\t\ttwo\t  three'
one         TWO   THREE
```

Testing with your real file but using \L for converting your data to lower case:

```
$ curl -sL -o- http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/product/1491356679_01827/4320.dict |head |sed -E 's/(.[^[:blank:]]*)([[:blank:]])(.*)/\1\2\L\3/g'
 AAREN  aa r ah n
AARIKA  aa r ah k ah
ABAGAEL ae b ah g iy l
ABAGAIL ah b ae g ey l
ABBE    ae b iy
ABBE(2) ae b ey
ABBEY   ae b iy
ABBI    ae b iy
ABBIE   ae b iy
ABBY    ae b iy
```

Comment: Good suggestions but I would really like to avoid creating a new file. Do you think you can come up with a way to just edit the same `names.dict` ?

Comment: @MarcoNeves You can use the first `sed -i`  solution that does in-place editing.

Comment: I tried it and got the following `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: Did you include `-E` in sed? It might require `-r` in your sed. Also try the perl alternative. For testing you can ommit the `-i` switch and if you are happy with the result you can add it later.

Comment: I edited the question and added a link to the file so you can test your answer when you have time, because I can't seem to make it work. Just convert it to lower case instead because for some reason it's all in caps

Comment: Yes I tested it using the same method and it worked fine as well, but it does not work for the file.

Comment: Using `sed -i` does not prevent the creation of an intermediate file.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou okay it's almost fully working. In `aaren` it's outputing `aa R AH N` instead. It's doing that for all the names.

Comment: @MarcoNeves OK - Solution corrected. The combination of tabs and spaces made previous solution to fail. Now it is corrected - See updated answer

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou This is good. It works perfectly, and do you know how I can write it to the file instead of printing it on the terminal? I would just copy/paste but terminal only shows part of the output since the file is so large.

Comment: @MarcoNeves Either use `sed -E -i` for in-place editing or add `>newfile` to the end of the command to create a new file.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very good approach to the problem if your `names.dict` is to have any kind of a larger size. Shells are slow and expensive.
You should use the shell language very sparingly and have most of the work done inside the programs you invoke.

E.g., you could do:

```
paste <(cut -d\  -f1  names.dict)  <(cut -d\  -f2-  names.dict |tr a-z A-Z )
```

or could use awk:

```
awk '{ 
     printf "%s ", $1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ", toupper($i); printf "\n"; 
}' names.dict
```

Having many iterations in a shell script and especially doing expensive operations such as invoking programs (`echo $toUpper | tr a-z A-Z`) or redirecting (`echo $line > temp`) on each of those iterations is definitely something you'll want to avoid if you want to write performant scripts.

**Edit -- sample file:**

Your problem is your sample file mixes tabs and spaces:

```
 # Assuming you're in an empty working directory
 mkdir workdir && cd $_
 #and you've downloaded the sample
 wget -O sample http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/product/1491356679_01827/4320.dict
 # you can downcase it and translate tabs to spaces
 tr 'A-Z\t' 'a-z ' <sample > names.dict
```

and then both the above scripts should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I kind of get how your suggestions work but I can't figure out how you are checking for the white space separating the name from the phonetic pronunciation ?

Comment: `awk` splits records on spaces or tabs by default. `cut` defaults to tabs, and I'm overriding it with `-d\  ` to spaces (`-d` stands for delimiter; `\ ` escaped space)

Comment: Oh I see, and up.txt would be names.dict in my case ? And the file has roughly 6000 lines so I see how it was not a good approach.

Comment: I tried to run your solution and it gave me the following error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. Could you maybe show how you would set it up?

Comment: The process substitution construct (`<()`) requires an advanced shell  such as `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`. If you're running it on `dash` (`/bin/sh` on ubuntu), you'll need to use tempfiles or fifos: `cut -d\  -f1  names.dict>a && cut -d\  -f2-  names.dict |tr a-z A-Z>b && paste a b
`

Comment: I tried that and it said `cut: the delimiter must be a single character`

Comment: `-d\  ` -- there's two spaces after the backward slash there. One as the argument to the backslash and the other as a separator between this argument and the next one.

Comment: Okay that fixed it, it converts it correctly but for some reason it's not converting the first letter, it just does the following instead:
    `stacy     s     T EY S IY`

Comment: check the edit, i added a link to the file of names so you can test your solution. Just convert it to lower case instead since for some reason it's all in caps already.

Comment: The file's mixing tabs and spaces. Do `tr '\t' ' ' < file` to replace tabs with spaces.